# Pipe in unordered list titles and randomize items

Tags: html, random, html-lists, listitem

I have a list of articles on my homepage, with a "read more" link to direct to the articles page:

```html
<div class="articles_list">
 <ul>
  <li>Article 1</li>
  <li>Article 2</li>
  <li>Article 3</li>
  <li>Article 4</li>
 </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="more"><a href="articles.html">and more...</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the titles, as I have more than 4 articles, and randomize them from time to time, without having to type them myself.
For example, the list could be:

```html
<div class="articles_list">
 <ul>
  <li>Article 5</li>
  <li>Article 1</li>
  <li>Article 8</li>
  <li>Article 4</li>
 </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="more"><a href="articles.html">and more...</a></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need bit of scripting here.. I have prepared a list of articles here (13). Similarly the arr (Array) needs to contain the list of articles you have. Rest all is dynamic code and it picks articles in randomized order.

```js
var arr = ['Article 1','Article 2','Article 3','Article 4','Article 5','Article 6','Article 7','Article 8','Article 9','Article 10','Article 11','Article 12','Article 13' ];


//Prepare 4 random articles.
var finalList = [];
var i = 0;
var node = document.getElementById('ulArticle');
while(true){
  var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var art = arr[randomNo];
  if(finalList.indexOf(art) == -1){
    finalList.push(art);
    node.innerHTML += '<li>'+art+'</li>';
    i++;
  }
  if(i >= 4){
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="articles_list">
 <ul id="ulArticle">
  
 </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="more"><a href="articles.html">and more...</a></div>
</div>
```